# UnicodeDecodeError: when decoding bytes to string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to decode a bytes value into a readable string using `decode()` function and `utf-16` as follows:

```
s1 = b'\xe2\x80\x99'

print(s1.decode("utf-16-le"))
```

Expecting a decoded string value, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 5, in <module>
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/encodings/utf_16_le.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_16_le_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-16-le' codec can't decode byte 0x99 in position 2: truncated data
```

There seems to be some error in the sequence character, but I can't understand why.

Comment: You might want to add what you expect the decoded string to look like. I'm guessing `’`

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that's UTF-16? Because...

- A UTF-16 encoded string's length is always an even number of bytes. Never 3 bytes, because 3 is odd.
- b'\xe2\x80\x99' is the UTF-8 encoding of [U+2019 Right Single Quotation Mark](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2019)